# Exact wavefunction of superconducting state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, superconductivity

Eventhough we know the mechanism of superconductivity (conventional superconductors) why couldn't we obtain the exact wavefunction of this state?

Edit: is there any simpler example in which we know the approximate wavefunction which captures the physics but the exact wavefunction is not known?

Comment: The wave-function is known as the BCS ansatz, it's known in the momentum space, and you can prove it is the exact ground state of the BCS Hamiltonian by variational method. Read the BCS paper and/or deGennes book for more details. Of course for more realistic Hamiltonian(s) the exact ground-state is not known. But even the Hamiltonian which could possibly lead to superconductivity is not really known neither (I'm thinking about high-temperature superconductor right now), so everything is fine, isn't it ?

Comment: @FraSchelle, thanks for your comment. But as you said the BCS ground state is obtained by variational method which presumably is not exact such that $H_{BCS} \Psi_{BCS}=E_0 \Psi_{BCS}$.

Comment: Yes it verifies this equation with $E_{0}=0$. The only point I forgot to mention is that you find the exact ground state and wave-function of the *mean-field* approximation of the BCS Hamiltonian. In short, the BCS Hamiltonian contains a 2-body term, that you decouple in the Cooper-pair sector to obtain a free-particle + self-consistent pairing term. Then you suspect the BCS ansatz to work, and you verify afterwards that it is the correct one, since it minimises the mean-field Hamiltonian self-consistently. An other method is to use the Bogoliubov-transformation, as discussed in deGennes book.

Comment: Perhaps you're interested in the wave function of the *full* (= non-mean-field) Hamiltonian. This one is indeed not known, for the simple reason it is a many-body non-linear problem :-) Note nevertheless that the mean-field decoupling can be justified afterwards as well : you calculate the fluctuations on top of your ground-state, and you realise they are irrelevant. So according to the renormalisation approach, you can safely say that you know the wave-function as much as you need to know it.

Comment: @FraSchelle: This is not really true. Some fluctuations have important corrections on the BCS results. For example, the corrections calculated by Gorkov and Melik-Barkhudarov changes the critical temperature by a numerical factor of order one.